# Can't uninstall .Net Framework 4.5.3

Tags: .net

For some reason, the required install EXE for 4.5.3 is missing from my PC.
So when I try to remove 4.5.3, I get prompted to supply the location of the EXE.

4.5.3 doesn't exist as a standalone version so I can't just download from Microsoft.com to replace the missing EXE.

Which product can I install to give me the 4.5.3 EXE?

[Have tried NetFxRepairTool]

Comment: Have you done any manual unistallation without wizard?

Comment: All versions after 4.0 are *binary replacements* for previous 4.x versions. The latest replaces all previous ones. The first Windows 10 edition came with 4.6. The latest version is 4.7.1. What OS are you running on and why did you try to uninstall 4.5.3? Did you encounter some problem and thought 4.5.3 was responsible?

Comment: 4.5.3 existed only for a very short moment, it was the first alpha release of what became 4.6.  This is not going to work out well of course, but if you don't tell us why you think you need it then nobody can help you.

Comment: Windows 7. When I try to install 4.7.1, after a while it prompts for the location of netfx_Full_LDR_x86.msi. I assume this is the 4.5.3 version which no longer exists on the machine.

Comment: @Hans, I was specific about what I wanted to find out - if the EXE was available. I've spent a while trying to fix the problem already so had reached the point where it would probably be easier/quicker just to rebuild the virtual machine if a simple download wasn't possible.